# Unit testing clients of Observables

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have the following method `go()` I'd like to test:

```
private Pair<String, String> mPair;

public void go() {
    Observable.zip(
            mApi.webCall(),
            mApi.webCall2(),
            new Func2<String, String, Pair<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public Pair<String, String> call(String s, String s2) {
                    return new Pair(s, s2);
                }
            }
    )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Pair<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Pair<String, String> pair) {
                    mApi.webCall3(pair.first, pair.second);
                }
            });
}
```

This method uses `Observable.zip()` to execute to http requests asynchronously, and merge them together in one `Pair`. In the end, another http request is executed with the result of these previous requests.

I'd like to verify that calling the `go()` method makes the `webCall()` and `webCall2()` requests, followed by the `webCall3(String, String)` request. Therefore, I'd like the following test to pass (using Mockito to spy the `Api`):

```
@Test
public void testGo() {
    /* Given */
    Api api = spy(new Api() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> webCall() {
            return Observable.just("First");
        }

        @Override
        public Observable<String> webCall2() {
            return Observable.just("second");
        }

        @Override
        public void webCall3() {
        }
    });

    Test test = new Test(api);

    /* When */
    test.go();

    /* Then */
    verify(api).webCall();
    verify(api).webCall2();
    verify(api).webCall3("First", "second");
}
```

However when running this, web calls are executed asynchronously, and my test executes the assertion before the subscriber is done causing my test to fail.

I have read that you can use `RxJavaSchedulersHook` and `RxAndroidSchedulersHook` to return `Schedulers.immediate()` for all methods, but this results in the test running indefinitely.

I am running my unit tests on a local JVM.

How can I achieve this, preferably without having to modify the signature of `go()`?

Comment: I know I can add a `Thread.sleep(x)` to 'ensure' my test thread waits until everything is done, but I want my tests to be fast. I have added the 1 second delay to avoid any races for this example.

Comment: use `toBlocking`. But your `go` should return the observable so you can actually be notified when stuff happen. I would use `doOnNext` to set the value of the pair instead of having your go function do it.

Comment: I don't want my `go()` method to return the observable.

Comment: After your last edit it seems like you are making the `mApi.webCall3` call on the main thread. Is this intentional or should that be observing on the io scheduler?

Comment: For the sake of this question, I just needed to call something on an object that I could verify like that. But yes, IRL that should've not been done on the mainthread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [found out](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html) that I can retrieve my `Schedulers` in a non-static way, basically injecting them into my client class. The `SchedulerProvider` replaces the static calls to `Schedulers.x()`:

```
public interface SchedulerProvider {

    Scheduler io();

    Scheduler mainThread();
}
```

The production implementation delegates back to `Schedulers`:

```
public class SchedulerProviderImpl implements SchedulerProvider {

    public static final SchedulerProvider INSTANCE = new SchedulerProviderImpl();

    @Override
    public Scheduler io() {
        return Schedulers.io();
    }

    @Override
    public Scheduler mainThread() {
        return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
    }
}
```

However, during tests I can create a `TestSchedulerProvider`:

```
public class TestSchedulerProvider implements SchedulerProvider {

    private final TestScheduler mIOScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    private final TestScheduler mMainThreadScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    @Override
    public TestScheduler io() {
        return mIOScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public TestScheduler mainThread() {
        return mMainThreadScheduler;
    }
}
```

Now I can inject the `SchedulerProvider` in to the `Test` class containing the `go()` method:

```
class Test {

    /* ... */

    Test(Api api, SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider) {
        mApi = api;
        mSchedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    }

    void go() {
        Observable.zip(
            mApi.webCall(),
            mApi.webCall2(),
            new Func2<String, String, Pair<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public Pair<String, String> call(String s, String s2) {
                    return new Pair(s, s2);
                }
            }
      )
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Pair<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Pair<String, String> pair) {
                    mApi.webCall3(pair.first, pair.second);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Testing this works as follows:

```
@Test
public void testGo() {
    /* Given */
    TestSchedulerProvider testSchedulerProvider = new TestSchedulerProvider();

    Api api = spy(new Api() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> webCall() {
            return Observable.just("First");
        }

        @Override
        public Observable<String> webCall2() {
            return Observable.just("second");
        }

        @Override
        public void webCall3() {
        }
    });

    Test test = new Test(api, testSchedulerProvider);

    /* When */
    test.go();
    testSchedulerProvider.io().triggerActions();
    testSchedulerProvider.mainThread().triggerActions();

    /* Then */
    verify(api).webCall();
    verify(api).webCall2();
    verify(api).webCall3("First", "second");
}
```

Comment: The only substantial difference between your self answer and my answer is a wrapper object that wraps your dependencies and you inject by constructor. Your question seemed to indicate you had a question about RxJava, not about your test structure or your framework.

Comment: There's some other stuff going on as well, such as not actively doing anything when calling the `go(Subscriber, Subscriber)` method (it still needs to be 'fired'), and there's substantial modification to the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

(Lambdas thanks to [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda))

For starters, I would rephrase go as:

```
private Pair<String, String> mPair;

public Observable<Pair<String, String>> go() {
    return Observable.zip(
                mApi.webCall(),
                mApi.webCall2(),
                (String s, String s2) -> new Pair(s, s2)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(pair -> mPair = pair);
}

public Pair<String, String> getPair() {
    return mPair;
}
```

`doOnNext` allows you to intercept the value that is being processed in the chain whenever someone will subscribe to the `Observable`

Then, I would call the test like that:

```
Pair result = test.go().toBlocking().lastOrDefault(null);
```

Then you can test what `result` is.

Comment: Hmm, what if the public api of the class requires `go()` to return an (unrelated) `boolean`? I am trying to find a generic solution to this problem.

Comment: Furthermore, if I understand correctly, just executing `go()` in production code does not 'fire' the calls right? It needs an 'end action' to make it execute? _I am not that familiar with RxJava yet ^^_

Comment: yes, my implementation of your `go` method does not do anything by itself, it requires someone to `subscribe` to the observable.

Comment: I would not recommend returning an unrelated boolean. Simply because then you could not test what you are trying to test. What you can do is define a method specifically for the observable, and a method that subscribe to the observable and returns that boolean value. This way you can test both functions.

Comment: My point is that I don't want to have to return the observable, because of reasons.

Comment: but I think you should have a method that does return an observable, for better reasons. (would it only be the ability to actually test it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `TestScheduler` and `TestSubscriber` in your tests. In order to use this you'll have to receive the observable that composes the zip so you can subscribe to that work with the testScheduler. Also you'll have to parameterize your schedulers. You won't have to change your `go` method's signature but you would have to parameterize the schedulers in underlying functionality. You could inject the schedulers by constructor, override a `protected` field by inheritance, or call to a `package` protected overload. I have written my examples assuming an overload that accepts the schedulers as arguments and returns the Observable.

The TestScheduler gives you a synchronous way to trigger async operator behavior in a predictable reproducible way. The TestSubscriber gives you a way to await termination and assert over values and signals received. Also you might want to be aware that the `delay(long, TimeUnit)` operator by default schedules work on the computation scheduler. You'll need to use the testScheduler there as well.

```
Scheduler ioScheduler = Schedulers.io();
Scheduler mainThreadScheduler =  AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();

public void go() {
    go(subscribeOnScheduler, mainThreadScheduler).toBlocking().single();
}

/*package*/ Observable<Pair<String, String>> go(Scheduler ioScheduler, Scheduler mainThreadScheduler) {
    return Observable.zip(
            mApi.webCall(),
            mApi.webCall2(),
            new Func2<String, String, Pair<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public Pair<String, String> call(String s, String s2) {
                    return new Pair(s, s2);
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Pair<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Pair<String, String>() {
                    mApi.webCall3(pair.first, pair.second);
                })
            })
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler);
}
```

Test code

```
@Test
public void testGo() {
    /* Given */
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    Api api = spy(new Api() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> webCall() {
            return Observable.just("First").delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler);
        }

        @Override
        public Observable<String> webCall2() {
            return Observable.just("second");
        }

        @Override
        public void webCall3() {
        }
    });

    Test test = new Test(api);

    /* When */
    test.go(testScheduler, testScheduler).subscribe(subscriber);
    testScheduler.triggerActions();
    subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();

    /* Then */
    verify(api).webCall();
    verify(api).webCall2();
    verify(api).webCall3("First", "second");
}
```

Comment: I read something about these too. But that would mean I have to use 'TestScheduler' in production code?

Comment: Is this a test or production? I interpreted your question to be about testing.

Comment: Of course, but we test production code, right? The method `go()` would be production code, `testGo()` the test that tests.. well.. `go()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would parameterize the scheduler to your method under test.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm writing for Android so that would mean I'd need to provide two `Schedulers` to the method, for background and UI thread.

Comment: This still requires me to return the observable, instead of subscribing directly in the `go()` method.

Comment: Yes and I would recommend that you always do that so you can merge or subscribe that observable in a line of other Rx work. Your production code could always hide this away by subscribing to it in your public interface but test against a package protected instance method that parameterizes the schedulers.

Comment: That doesn't seem efficient. I do like this approach the best though,  but I'm hoping there's another way without having to change the client code.

Comment: This still requires me to return the `Observable`, and I cannot test the behavior of the `Subscriber`. I have edited the question to express my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that took one more step in order to be solved.:

```
existingObservable
     .zipWith(Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), new Func1<> ...)
     .subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.computation())
```

Was still not using the provided TestScheduler *schedulersProvider* returned. It was necessary to specify *.subscribeOn()* on the individual streams that i was zipping in order to work.:

```
existingObservable.subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.computation())
     .zipWith(Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.computation()), new Func1<> ...)
     .subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.computation())
```

*Note that schedulersProvider is a mock returning the TestScheduler of my Test!*